# Replace services' URLs with Grunt based on environment

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gruntjs, continuous-deployment

At the moment I'm having some problems with my continuous delivery system implementation because every time I want to push my changes into production I have to manually change the URLs of my services.

Example:
On the dev system I work locally on my computer and so I have all my URLs set to http://localhost/ but when I push to production I have to change all this URLs into http://www.mywebsite.it

How can I can make Grunt change this URLs based on the task called (grunt serve -> dev env, grunt build -> prod env) ?

P.S: The URLs to change are in multiple files and in different languages and frameworks (PHP, AngularJs, NodeJS)

Comment: What continuous-deployment tool are you using?

Comment: I use Jenkins..